# Tablet whiteboard app w e-pencil

Tags: undergraduate-education, software, interactive-teaching, online-instruction

(I've generalized the original question as @BrendanW.Sullivan suggests.)

I would appreciate recommendations for a whiteboard app for a tablet using an e-pencil. For me: an iPad, using an Apple pencil. For others, please specify the hardware & OpSys & software.

I just want to be able to draw in colors and erase easily, like a physical whiteboard. The whiteboard will be shown to my (remote) students; I don't need them to also access the whiteboard. Other posted questions seek special capabilities (e.g., LaTeX support). My needs are more basic.

Free would be nice but my school will reimburse me so I can also purchase. What I see online is a bewildering variety of products not easily evaluated.

Comment: Is it reasonable to ask you to modify this question to seek *tablet apps*, and answers can specify whether they available on iOS or Android or both?

Comment: I just got myself an XP Pen. It's drawing pad, not a tablet, so you have to look at your screen when you write. But it's way cheaper and works well so far.

Comment: I just downloaded the LectureNotes app (on Android tablet), based on reviews and recommendations. Seems like it might fit your basic needs. Also allows you to import a pdf, so you can type up chosen examples in LaTeX then open the pdf in this app to annotate them and record as you do so. At least, that's what I plan on trying out. If this works well, I'll come back and write this up as an answer to OP.

Comment: Here's a link I just got  (maybe from the Math Mamas facebook group, maybe from another fb group for educators) on this very topic: https://zapier.com/blog/best-online-whiteboard/

Comment: I've followed the advice in an earlier @SueVanHattum link and am using [*Educreations*](https://www.educreations.com/).

Comment: Openboard (https://openboard.ch/index.en.html) is great (free, easy to use and open source), with many options. I use it with a Macbook combined with a XP Pen Artist 12 drawing pad. However, it seems that it is not designed for tablets.